# Nodejs render multiple items with the same name

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to render using underscore js, and instead of making a template for each, I decided to use one for all. However, this code only renders the last item( accessories : luggage). Any way to make it work?

```
exports.maccess = function(req, res) {
    collectionp.find({ "primary_category_id": "mens-accessories-gloves"}).toArray(function(err, gloves) {
        collectionp.find({ "primary_category_id": "mens-accessories-ties"}).toArray(function(err, ties) {
            collectionp.find({ "primary_category_id": "mens-accessories-luggage"}).toArray(function(err, luggage) {
                res.render("maccess", { 
                    _     : _, 
                    accessories : ties,
                    accessories : gloves,
                    accessories : luggage
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If ties, gloves, and luggage are all arrays, and you're using the same template on all of them, try just passing them along as a single array, e.g.

```
accessories : ties.concat(gloves).concat(luggage)
```

Try it out and let me know if it works or if I've misunderstood something..

Answer (score 1):

Javascript object cannot contain multiple entries with the same key (in your case - `accessories`).

You have to write something like:

```
accessories: [ties, gloves, luggage]
```

(and use it in the template: `accessories[0]`, `accessories[1]`, `accessories[2]`)

or:

```
accessories: {
  ties: ties,
  gloves: gloves,
  luggage: luggage
}
```

And use it: `accessories.ties`, `accessories.gloves`, etc